# Can't print the concatenated strings (Using Python 2.7)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Please help me, I am trying to print the SSID with the password of my WiFi. Here I am getting a small problem in concatenating the strings. Can't figure out where the problem exactly is.

```
import subprocess
import re

command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
network_names_list = re.findall(r"(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)

for network_name in network_names_list:
    command = "netsh wlan show profile " + network_name + " key=clear"
    print command
    break
```

Output:  key=clear

Comment: hi , can you add the ouput of the variable `networks`

Comment: yes, the output is:  key=clear

Comment: Is this Python3 or Python (Python2)? If it is Python3, then you got an error in your `print`. because you need paranthesis around your variable `command`.

Comment: It's not working in both Python2 and Python3. Getting Same output

Comment: Your code **does** **not** work for Python3 for two reasons: 1. `subprocess.check_output` will return a `bytes`-object, not a string, so the regular-expression will fail. 2. your `print` statement will also not work in Python3 because it's a function there, not a statement.